# Copy data from HTML table to another HTML page

Tags: php, html

I'm not a complete noob, but I don't have more than a handful of months experience with `HTML` any help with this will be appreciated. I have a webpage that shows a table with several columns and several rows. I have an `Edit` link at the end of each row that takes you to another page that is supposed to make the data in the row editable. I can make the first page and the link takes me to another page, but i can't figure out how to get the data from the table row on the first page and put into the table on the second page. I want it to go from a table with 1 row selected to a table with 2 columns and 1 row for each of the columns in the first table.

Here's the page with the table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Testing PHP</title>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<!--h2>This will pull down all the Names from the QDef table</h2-->
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
    <p>4 Results</p>
    <table class="tab"id="NameTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="cell">Edit</th>
                <th class="cell">TempID</th>
                <th class="cell">Name</th>
                <th class="cell">CountryCode</th>
                <th class="cell">Budget</th>
                <th class="cell">Used</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row1">
                <td>
                    <a Href="#" data-id="1" data-target="TempIDColumn" onclick="window.open('FormToEditMaterial.php','FormToEditMaterial');">Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td contenteditable>1</td>
                <td contenteditable>Win Temp</td>
                <td contenteditable>TH</td>
                <td contenteditable>1000000.000000000</td>
                <td contenteditable>60000.000000000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row">
                <td>
                    <a Href="#" data-id="2" data-target="TempIDColumn" onclick="window.open('FormToEditMaterial.php','FormToEditMaterial');">Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td contenteditable>2</td>
                <td contenteditable>Test Temp</td>
                <td contenteditable>UK</td>
                <td contenteditable>100000.000000000</td>
                <td contenteditable>5000.000000000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row1">
                <td>
                    <a Href="#" data-id="3" data-target="TempIDColumn" onclick="window.open('FormToEditMaterial.php','FormToEditMaterial');">Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td contenteditable>3</td>
                <td contenteditable>Number 3</td>
                <td contenteditable>UK</td>
                <td contenteditable>1000000.000000000</td>
                <td contenteditable>50000.000000000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row">
                <td>
                    <a Href="#" data-id="4" data-target="TempIDColumn" onclick="window.open('FormToEditMaterial.php','FormToEditMaterial');">Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td contenteditable>4</td>
                <td contenteditable>Number 4</td>
                <td contenteditable>US</td>
                <td contenteditable>50000.000000000</td>
                <td contenteditable>.000000000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the Page that is supposed to allow me to edit the data from the table in the first page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>FormToEditMaterial</title>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <table id="FormToEditMaterialTable">
        <tr>
            <th contenteditable="false" >Field Name</th>
            <th contenteditable="false">Field to be edited</th>
        </tr>
        <tr contenteditable>
            <td id="TempIDColumn" contenteditable="false">Name of Field</td>
            <td>Data to be updated</td>
        </tr>
        <tr contenteditable>
            <td id="NameColumn" contenteditable="false">Name of field 2</td>
            <td>Data 2 to be updated</td>
        </tr>
        <tr contenteditable>
            <td id="CountryCodeColumn" contenteditable="false">Name of field 3</td>
            <td>Data 3 to be updated</td>
        </tr>
        <tr contenteditable>
            <td id="BudgetColumn" contenteditable="false">Name of field 4</td>
            <td>Data 4 to be updated</td>
        </tr>
        <tr contenteditable>
            <td id="UsedColumn" contenteditable="false">Name of field 5</td>
            <td>Data 5 to be updated</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" name="SubmitUpdate" class="ok" value="Submit Update"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I've seen where people use forms and `$POST` to get the data from one page to another, but I'm not using a form. I'm actually using `PHP` and this is the resulting `HTML` and what is being pulled from the SQL server. However, I just need help with getting this working in `HTML`, I will figure out how to translate it into the `PHP`. Here is what the files look like that I'm working with:

[JSFiddle TestingPHP - First Table](https://jsfiddle.net/MidlothainAdair/j3gmpa76/)

[JSFiddle FormToEditMaterial - Second Table](https://jsfiddle.net/MidlothainAdair/ek4hxj65/)

If you need more info let me know and I'll provide what ever I can.

**Edit**
Here's the updated FormToEditMaterial file, I did not update the JSFiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>FormToEditMaterial</title>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <table id="FormToEditMaterialTable">
        <tr>
            <th contenteditable="false" >Field Name</th>
            <th contenteditable="false">Field to be edited</th>
        </tr>
        <tr contenteditable>
            <td id="TempIDColumn" contenteditable="false">Name of Field</td>
            <td>Data to be updated</td>
        </tr>
        <tr contenteditable>
            <td id="NameColumn" contenteditable="false">Name of field 2</td>
            <td>Data 2 to be updated</td>
        </tr>
        <tr contenteditable>
            <td id="CountryCodeColumn" contenteditable="false">Name of field 3</td>
            <td>Data 3 to be updated</td>
        </tr>
        <tr contenteditable>
            <td id="BudgetColumn" contenteditable="false">Name of field 4</td>
            <td>Data 4 to be updated</td>
        </tr>
        <tr contenteditable>
            <td id="UsedColumn" contenteditable="false">Name of field 5</td>
            <td>Data 5 to be updated</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" name="SubmitUpdate" class="ok" value="Submit Update"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <form>
        TempID: <input type="text" name="1"><br>
        Name: <input type="text" name="2"><br>
        CountryCode: <input type="text" name="3"><br>
        Budget: <input type="text" name="4"><br>
        Used: <input type="text" name="5"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's the new FormToEditMaterial.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "ServerName";
$username = "User";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "DBName";
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername;database=$dbname",     $username,$password);
$row = array();

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$row = $_POST;

$q = 'UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET Name = ?, CountryCode = ?, Budget = ?, Used = ? WHERE TempID = ?';
$sth = $db->prepare($q);
$sth->execute(array($row['Name'], $row['CountryCode'], $row['Budget'], $row['Used'], $row['TempID']));
print_r($db->errorInfo());
echo "<br>";
var_dump($sth);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($row);

if ($sth->rowCount() == 1) header('Location: Index.php');
}
else if (!empty($_GET['id']))
{
$q = 'SELECT TempID, Name, CountryCode, Budget, Used FROM MyTable WHERE TempID = ?';
$sth = $db->prepare($q);
$sth->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$row = $sth->fetch();
}
else
{
// Show error message here
}
?>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<p>
    <label>TempID:
    <input type="text" name="TempID" value="<?php echo $row['TempID']?>"></label>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Name:
    <input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $row['Name']?>"></label>
</p>
<p>
    <label>CountryCode:
    <input class="CountryCode" type="text" name="CountryCode" value="<?php echo $row['CountryCode']?>"></label>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Budget:
    <input type="text" name="Budget" value="<?php echo $row['Budget']?>"></label>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Used:
    <input type="text" name="Used" value="<?php echo $row['Used']?>">    </label>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</p>
</form>
```

And here's the Index.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "ServerName";
$username = "User";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "DBName";
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername;database=$dbname", $username,$password);
$q = 'SELECT TempID, Name, CountryCode, Budget, Used FROM MyTable';
?>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>TempID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>CountryCode</th>
        <th>Budget</th>
        <th>Used</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($db->query($q) as $row) :?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="FormToEditMaterial.php?id=<?php echo $row['TempID']?>">Edit</a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['TempID']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Name']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['CountryCode']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Budget']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Used']?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Add a query string to the links so the "edit page" knows which row you are editing, e.g. `<a href="FormToEditMaterial.php?id=3">`. Next, you add a form on the edit page that will submit to the database and which takes you back to the main page.

Comment: You're either going to need a buttload of JavaScript, to make the data editable in this page or you can load a form with all of the data using the same database request.. Regardless, there are too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: For example, on solution might involve using [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I can use a form, but not on the first page, it's created using PHP based on the table that I'm querying in my DB.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I looked on Quora, I didn't see anything that fit what I am looking for, but I'll look again.

Comment: @Midas I will try that, but how to I fill the form with the data once it's assigned an id? I do already have the `data-id` mentioned for each row, would this be the same thing?

Comment: Don't just look, propose. Put your question out there in the ether and see what comes back.

Comment: @Mike Why can't you use a database?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I don't need the whole table, just the one row that needs to be updated. I'll look up the `$_SESSION`

Comment: @Midas How would I use my DB to do this? My users will select what row needs edited and then need some way of editing that row. That's why I have the second page that has the fields editable. I tried using a form, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly as the fields are not being populated. I'll add an edit that shows the new file.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez If I edit it in the first page how do I send just that row back to the DB for update? I'm still new to PHP and don't know this.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I've never used Ajax, I'll have to look into that as well.

Comment: Mike, maybe it's time to give an oportunity to my answer, the code is shorter and simpler. Sooner or later you will have to use ajax, so, why not now? Just replace the "database" (the array) with your database and display the appropiate fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a quick example:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

In *index.php*:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('host', 'username', 'password');
$q = 'SELECT TempID, Name, CountryCode, Budget, Used FROM MyTable';
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>TempID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>CountryCode</th>
            <th>Budget</th>
            <th>Used</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php foreach ($db->query($q) as $row) :?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="FormToEditMaterial.php?id=<?php echo $row['TempID']?>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['TempID']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Name']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['CountryCode']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Budget']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Used']?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In *FormToEditMaterial.php*:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('sqlite:db.sqlite3');
$row = array();

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $row = $_POST;

    $q = 'UPDATE MyTable SET Name = ?, CountryCode = ?, Budget = ?, Used = ? WHERE TempID = ?';
    $sth = $db->prepare($q);
    $sth->execute(
        array($row['Name'], $row['CountryCode'], $row['Budget'], $row['Used'], $row['TempID'])
    );

    if ($sth->rowCount() == 1) header('Location: index.php');
}
else if (!empty($_GET['id']))
{
    $q = 'SELECT TempID, Name, CountryCode, Budget, Used FROM MyTable WHERE TempID = ?';
    $sth = $db->prepare($q);
    $sth->execute(array($_GET['id']));
    $row = $sth->fetch();
}
else
{
    // Show error message here
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <p>
        <label>TempID:
        <input type="text" name="TempID" value="<?php echo $row['TempID']?>"></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Name:
        <input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $row['Name']?>"></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>CountryCode:
        <input type="text" name="CountryCode" value="<?php echo $row['CountryCode']?>"></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Budget:
        <input type="text" name="Budget" value="<?php echo $row['Budget']?>"></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Used:
        <input type="text" name="Used" value="<?php echo $row['Used']?>"></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

This example doesn't include any error checking whatsoever.

Comment: I tried this, but there is nothing in `$_POST` so nothing is getting passed through to the form. The form doesn't show either for that matter.

Comment: @Mike It should work out of the box (see screenshots). You only need to change the database details.

Comment: Here's what I've got in my files:
[QDef](https://jsfiddle.net/MidlothainAdair/L3akqpj8/)


[EditQDefForm](https://jsfiddle.net/MidlothainAdair/eczff0yc/)

Comment: @Mike because you are echo'ing `$row` instead of `$selectedRow`.

Comment: I updated my code to have the `$selectedRow` be what is echoed. There is still nothing in `$_POST` so nothing is being put into `$selectedRow`. When I run this it goes straight to the `else`, shouldn't it go to the first part of the `if` and get the data from the row that has the matching `Id`?

Comment: @Mike Yes, in fact the if should be switched to check for `$_POST` data first. I don't know why I wrote it that way...

Comment: Where is `$_POST` supposed to be getting the rows info from? I don't see anywhere that it's being collected?

Comment: Okay, so it should be:
`if(!empty($_POST['Id']))`

Comment: @Mike `$_POST` is the form data. `$_GET` is URL data.

Comment: @Mike Ideally you would use `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: I updated my code to match your edit. But `$_POST` is not getting set. Where is it supposed to get set? When I click the `edit` on the QDef page?

Comment: No, `$_POST` is set when the form is submitted. `$_GET` is set when the edit link is clicked.

Comment: Okay, I just created a local website to test this. I've copied your examples from above and created the table `MyTable` in a testing DB that I've got and can connect to. In the `Index.php` page I can see the 100 rows I generated for it. I've got this to work. Now I've got to figure out what I'm missing in my other website to get it working there as well. Thanks!

Comment: When I hit submit, nothing happens. Does it automatically go back through the `IF`?

Comment: @Mike Yes, if the number of affected rows in the database is 1, this line should send you back to index.php: `if ($sth->rowCount() == 1) header('Location: index.php');`

Comment: It doesn't, i update just one thing and the screen flashes at me then nothing.

Comment: @Mike What is nothing?

Comment: It stays on the Edit form, it doesn't go anywhere. I click `submit` the screen flashes and stays right where it was. My edit is still there, but when I navigate to the Index.php my edit has not taken effect.

Comment: @Mike Might be an SQL error. Try `print_r($db->errorInfo())` after `$sth->execute()`

Comment: Here's the print out `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) `. The `$sth` and `$row` do have values and seem to be correct, but I've no idea what that above means?

Comment: Well, zero in the first key means there was no error, so I don't see what the problem is... Can you reupload your code?

Comment: They have been re-uploaded under Edit 2 above

Comment: No, nothing changes.

Comment: The `$sth->rowCount()` is 0

Comment: @Mike Why are you specifying database `dbo` in the update query?

Comment: I thought it would help since i have several schemas. It didn't and I just never took it back out.

Comment: @Mike I would try to leave it out, since you don't have that in the select statements.

Comment: I updated my code when you mentioned it. It doesn't make any difference. Here's what `var_dump($sth);` prints after the `$sth->execute(array($row['Name'], $row['CountryCode'], $row['Budget'], $row['Used'], $row['TempID']));`

Value:
`object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(83) "UPDATE MyTable SET Name = ?, CountryCode = ?, Budget = ?, Used = ? WHERE TempID = ?" } `

Comment: I know that `$row` has values, I can print that as well.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Have you tried putting fixed data in the update query?

Comment: I have. I think I figured it out. The user account that I'm using doesn't have `Update` permission on the DB. I'll have to get that fixed to see if it's working or not.

Comment: Yep, the user account I was using didn't have `update` permissions. It works now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is a good solution for your problem, because you won't need to jump to a secondary page, not even refresh the page! Next code is an example and it works like this:

1. Every row in the HTML table has one button to save changes.
2. The click event of every button calls the ajax function with the data values.
3. The ajax function calls "update.php" with the data values as POST parameters.
4. "update.php" gets the data as $_POST values and updates the database record.
5. "update.php" sends a success message back to the ajax function to display it.

In order to test it, create two files with the given names, copy-paste next codes and run! (You don't need anything else but those codes).

**main.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//--------------------------------------------------
function myAjax ( id )
{ if ( ! confirm( "Save data for id=" + id + " ?" ) )
     return;
  $.ajax( { type    : 'POST',
            url     : 'update.php',
            data    : { 'id'    : id,
                        'name'  : $("#name"+id).val(), // VALUE FROM EDIT FIELD.
                        'phone' : $("#phone"+id).val(), // VALUE FROM EDIT FIELD.
                      },
            success : function ( result )
                      { alert( result ); },
            error   : function ( xhr )
                      { alert( "error" ); }
          }
        );
}
//--------------------------------------------------
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr><td>NAME</td>
          <td>PHONE</td>
          <td></td>
      </tr>
<?php
//--------------------------------------------------
// SAMPLE DATA.
$database = Array( Array( "id"    => "1",
                          "name"  => "Mike",
                          "phone" => "123" ),
                   Array( "id"    => "2",
                          "name"  => "Midas",
                          "phone" => "456" ),
                   Array( "id"    => "3",
                          "name"  => "Jay",
                          "phone" => "789" )
                 );
$i = 1;
foreach ( $database as $row ) // DISPLAY "DATABASE" ROWS.
{ echo "<tr><td><input type='text' id='name" . $row["id"] .
                       "' value='" . $row["name"] . "'/></td>\n" .
       "    <td><input type='text' id='phone" . $row["id"] .
                       "' value='" . $row["phone"] . "'/></td>\n" .
       "    <td><button onclick='myAjax(\"" . $row["id"] .
                             "\")'>Save changes</button></td>\n" .
       "</tr>";
  $i++;
}
//--------------------------------------------------
?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**update.php**

```
<?php
// CHECK IF VALUES ARE COMING FROM AJAX.
if ( isset( $_POST[ "id"    ] ) &&
     isset( $_POST[ "name"  ] ) &&
     isset( $_POST[ "phone" ] ) )
   { // "update my_table set name=$_POST[ "name"  ],
     //                     phone=$_POST[ "phone" ]
     //                  where id=$_POST[ "id"    ]
     echo "Record " . $_POST[ "id" ] . " updated with " .
          $_POST[ "name"  ] . " and " . $_POST[ "phone" ];
   }
?>
```

Oops! Just fixed one little problem, ready to run!

If you right-click the webpage to see the code, you will notice the input fields have the ids "name1", "name2", ..., and "phone1", "phone2", .... This method gives every textbox a unique id (necessary for ajax function to get the value entered by user and send it to PHP). The code in charge of this is :

```
id='name" . $row["id"] .
"' value=
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but a fallback in pure PHP is still desired.

Comment: PHP and Ajax are the perfect marriage!